# Milnor's appendix on classification of 1-manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to understand Milnor's proof of the classification of 1-manifolds, given in the appendix of his boook "Topology from a differentiable point of view".

***Any smooth, connected one dimensional manifold is diffeomorphic to either to the circle $S^1$ or to some interval of real numbers.***

Remark: I thought doing in many posts as part 1, and so on, but I think it will lose the idea. However, if some moderator thinks that will be better I will do it :D.

To proof that, he gives a definition and a lemma,

**Definition**

> A map $f: I\to M$ is a parametrization by arc-length if $f$ maps $I$ diffeomorphically onto an open subset $\dagger$ of $M$, and if the "velocity vector" $d f_s(1) \quad\varepsilon\quad T M_{f(s)}$ has unit length, for each $s \varepsilon I$.
> Any given local parametrization $I^\prime\to M$ can be transformed into a parametrization by arc-length by a straightforward change of variables.

**Lemma**

> Let $f: I\to M$ and $g: J\to M$ be parametrizations by arc-length. Then $f(I) \cap g(J)$ has at most two components. If it has only one component, then $f$ can be extended to a parametrization by arc-length of the union $f(I) \cup g(J)$. If it has two components, then M must be diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

Here is the beginning of the proof

**Proof**

> Clearly $g^{-1}$ of maps some relatively open subset of $I$ diffeomorphically onto a relatively open subset of $J$. Furthermore the derivative of $g^{-1}$ of is equal to $\pm 1$ everywhere.

My doubts are:
To prove that let $U=f(I)\cap g(J)$, so
$$h:=g^{-1}\circ f:f^{-1}(U)\to g^{-1}(U)$$
that "open subset of $I$" is $f^{-1}(U)$ so $h$ is a diffeormophism. From there $h(s)=g^{-1}\circ f(s)$, then $dh_s=dg^{-1}_{f(s)}(df_s)$.

I know that $\|df_s(1)\|=\|dg_t(1)\|=1$, and $dg^{-1}_t=(dg_{g^{-1}(t)})^{-1}$, so

$$\begin{aligned}\|dh_s(1)\|&=\|dg^{-1}_{f(s)}(df_s(1))\|\\&=\|(dg_{g^{-1}(f(s))})^{-1}(df_s(1))\|\\&=\|(dg_{h(s)})^{-1}(df_s(1))\|\end{aligned}$$

**(1)** But I don't know what to do from that. Another way I'm trying is:

From $h(s)=g^{-1}\circ f(s)$, we get $g(h(s))=f(s)$, then $dg_{h(s)}(dh_s)=df_s$. Applying in $1$, we get $dg_{h(s)}(dh_s(1))=df_s(1)$, so $dg_{h(s)}(h'(s))=df_s(1)$ ,but I get stuck again.

Then he continues:

[image]

So $\Gamma:=\{(s,t)\in f^{-1}(U)\times g{-1}(U)|f(s)=g(t)\}\subset I\times J$, then $\Gamma=\operatorname{graph}(h)$ and it is a closed subset. I get this, my second doubt is:

**(2)** What information about the intersection $U$ will $\Gamma$ give?

**(3)** Why does he say that $h$ is "locally" a diffeomorphism?

As $h'(s)=\pm 1$, then $h(s)=s+b$ or $h(s)=-s+b$, where $b$ is a constant. In the proof says that $\Gamma$ consists of line segments of slope $\pm 1$.

**(4)** The word "segments" means that $\Gamma$ can be made of many pieces, but if $h$ is a diffeomorphism, and its domain $f^{-1}(U)$ is connected(or I'm wrong?), it is not $\Gamma$ made of one part?

Then...

[image]

**(5)** I do not understand why there can be at most one of these segments ending on each of the 4 edges of $I\times J$.
In order to this post not being huge I will do a second part. Thank you.

Comment: Please take better last two pictures so I can snip it.

Comment: @Invisible thank you very much!!