# On Milnor's proof of classifying 1-manifolds part 2

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential

Continuing with this post:

[Milnor's appendix on classification of 1-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483357/milnors-appendix-on-classification-of-1-manifolds)

I want to show that $h$ is well defined. For that I must prove:

$\theta:=\dfrac{2\pi t}{\alpha-a}\in<0,2\pi>$.

Knowing that $t\in <a,\beta>$ I Just get to

$$a<t<\beta\to 0<t-a<\beta-a$$

$$0<\dfrac{1}{\beta-a}<\dfrac{1}{t-a}$$

To appear $\alpha-a$, do I have to analyse many cases? Or is there a simpler way? Then have to analyse in the overlaps.

Thank you.